# Average calculation using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, average

I have an `EMP` table in SQL Server that looks something like this

```
ID          T_Date  Jid   Emp_Cost  Con_Cost    IsActive 
--------------------------------------------------------
13178       null    214      0         0          0
12797       null    214      0         55         1
11906       null    214      0         55         1
12916       null    214      0         58         1
```

I am executing the below query

```
SELECT 
    AVG(CASE WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN Con_Cost ELSE Emp_Cost END) cost 
FROM 
    EMP 
WHERE 
    Jid = 214 
    AND (T_Date IS NULL OR T_Date >= sysdate);
```

My expected cost value must be 56.

Can anybody help me with this?

Arun

Answer (score 0):

`AVG` actually works fine, since it does an average of the sum of 0+55+55+58 divided by **the number of rows in the result set**.

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
select distinct
    sum(case when IsActive = 1 then con_cost else emp_cost end) over () / 
    count(case when IsActive = 1 then 1 else null end) over ()
from emp
where Jid = 214
    and (T_Date is null or T_Date >= sysdatetime());
```

or maybe are you looking for:

```
select avg(con_cost)
from emp
where isActive = 1
    and Jid = 214
    and (T_Date is null or T_Date >= sysdatetime());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since aggregate functions ignore `null` values, you can use `nullif()` to change `0` to `null` like so:

```
select avg(nullif(case 
   when IsActive = 1 then Con_Cost
   else Emp_Cost
   end
   ,0)) as cost
from EMP
where Jid = 214
  and (T_Date is null or T_Date >= sysdatetime());
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NPBOP19522

returns

```
+------+
| cost |
+------+
|   56 |
+------+
```

note: I changed `sysdate` to `sysdatetime()`, though I do not know if that is the intent of your query.

Answer (score 0):

This can work too. http://rextester.com/QIXA57971

```
SELECT 
     AVG(CASE WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN Con_Cost ELSE Emp_Cost END) cost 
FROM 
    EMP 
WHERE 
    Jid = 214 
    AND (T_Date IS NULL OR T_Date >= GETDATE()) AND IsActive = 1;
```

Result

```
cost   
-----
56
```